# How do I order by artist's name just like A-Z?

Tags: android, sdk, deezer

I use the Deezer API to request user favourite artists,http://api.deezer.com/user/me/artists,but the results order by id,how can i order by artist's name just like A-Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate all data of artist in `ArrayList` and just use `Collections.sort(artistList);`
This will work because the items in `artistList` are String's, and String implements Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the deezer API, but why not parsing the result as object in an ArrayList and then sort it by name attribute ?